# Data Binding library - error in automatically generated classes

Tags: android

After update Android Studio to version 3.2, occurred an errors in one of my projects and it can't compile. I write this project on Kotlin, and also use Data Binding Library. This is one of the [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IePyk.png). The others are similar, and comes from automatically generated classes from Data Binding Library. This is one of the generated [classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLTQy.png). You can see that **com.helpkarma.campaigns.Data** package can't be finded, and because of that, occurs an error in other classes that use this generated class.
I will be very thankful if someone can help me!

Comment: **Rebuild project** might solve the issue.

Comment: I tried, but doesn't work. Tried **Invalidate Caches/Restart** - also without success